# Как разместить 'х' (кнопка удаления) в input поле?

Tags: html, css, input, button, label

```js
$( document ).ready( function () {
 /*x in input form*/
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.formBr>label').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next().val('');
  });
})});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
                
                <div class="formBr">
                <label>x</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form_name" name="form_name" placeholder="Enter your name"  />
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: А что не так сейчас? Все ведь работает. Нужно только jquery подключить

Comment: да! но как разместить ее внутри поля??))

Comment: Ну так на css задайте ей позицию поверх поля

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задаем для `.formBr {position:relative;}`, а для `.formBr label {position:absolute}`.

Так же посоветовал бы вам указать для `label` атрибут `for` равный идентификатору инпута, чтобы при нажатии на этот самый `label` фокус оставался на инпуте. Или же в вашем обработчике нажатия изменить `$(this).next().val('');` на `$(this).next().val('').focus();`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*x in input form*/
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.formBr>label').on('click', function() {
      $(this).next().val('');
    });
  })
});
```

```css
.formBr {
  position: relative;
}

.formBr input {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px 0 30px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.formBr label {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">

  <div class="formBr">
    <label for="form_name">x</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form_name" name="form_name" placeholder="Enter your name" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось :)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте для `<label>x</label>` абсолютное позиционирование и `z-index` больше, чем у input-поля. Также на забудьте задать его родителю `formBr` свойство `position: relative;`.